# Non-linear ODE for which backward Euler becomes unstable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

One way to solve initial value problems of the type

$\dot{x} = f(x), \; x(0) = 0$

numerically is to use the backwards Euler method

$x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \Delta t f(x_{n+1}), \; n = 1,\ldots \\
x_{1} = x_{0}$.

It is well known that this method is unconditionally stable
in the sense that when applied to the equation $\dot{x} = \lambda x$
with $\lambda < 0$, the solution will not blow up regardless of
the choice of time step $\Delta t$. The fact that the backwards
Euler method is stable in this sense, does it imply that it is 
unconditionally stable also for every non-linear ODE (with bounded 
solutions, or over a finite time interval with no finite escape)?

Is there an example of a non-linear ODE with bounded solutions for
which the backward Euler becomes unstable for some $\Delta t$?

Cheers, Ingrid

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If I understood in correctly it doesn't really answer my question, just provides a motivation for the study of the linear ODE.